# XML referencing to an id with # or not?

Tags: xml, reference, identifier, xpointer

My current project consists of letters which are in collections. Each collection has an id and the letters refer to these ids.
Coming from the "TEI world", I thought it would be the best solution to do that with #:

```
<collection xml:id="1"/>

<letter is_included_in="#1"/>
```

I thought that is the usal and best way to do that and also intended by the XPointer standard.

Recently, I have learned there is a dt:type="idref" type in XML Schema to handle references to ids. This way it would be without the #.

So, I'm a little bit confused right now.

What is best pratice here and a the most semantic way to handle id references inside one xml document?
Or, in other words: How would any human or non-human reader which doesn't know my XMl schema expect me to do this?

Comment: Where are you getting the _#_ idea from? It's used in HTML anchor _href_ attributes because it represents the fragment part of a URL and instructs the browser to scroll to a certain element in the current page. In other contexts it may not make much sense.

Comment: It is part of the TEI standard. In TEI all entities with IDs are allways refered with #. E.g. <persName ref="#abehn.aeh">Behn, Aphra</persName>, refering to a <person xml:id="abehn.aeh"> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a simple referencing scheme that does not have to make sub-references, I recommend that you do not pre-pend all references with hash characters (`#`):

```
<collection xml:id="c1"/>

<letter is_included_in="c1"/>
```

- At the base level, standard practice is for identifier and reference to match
  exactly; `@id` and `@idref` match exactly.
- Historically, `#` in a reference is used to precede a reference to a subpart.  (See specifically the widely adopted standard use of hash marks in HTML `@href` to introduce a *fragment identifier* to refer to a named part of an HTML page.)  TEI and XPointer built upon this convention in URIs.
- The [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) requires that attribute values of type ID [must match](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id) the [Name production](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name), which prohibits id's from starting with a number.